# How to listen to deselection of row in JavaFX tableview?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I have a tableview with SelectionMode.MULTIPLE:

```
    table.setEditable(true);
    table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

    table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().forEach(System.out::println);
            });
```

Selecting rows works finde, but if a deselect a row again (by clicking ctrl+left-click) the listener doesn't react to that immediately. What I have to do to deselect a row is the following:

1. Select lets say *'Rob', 'Peter', 'Max' and 'John'* (Either by selecting them individualy with ctrl+left-click or all of them together by shift+left click)
2. Unselect *'Peter'* by clicking ctrl+left-click (now this row has a weird blue border and the listener didn't detected the change)
3. Deselect another row (Now this row has this weird border and 'Peter' is row looks normal)
4. Reselect the previous row (Now the listener detects that I unselected *'Peter'*)
   [image]

Comment: I have reproduced this on my system as well. It is a bug. Please log it here: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com.

If you want me to log it for you just let me know.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. Give me time to do some testing and I'll check, but typically for multiple selection you should register a listener with the **list** of selected items, not the single selected item (which is the last selected item).

Comment: @James_D was right. I have to add the listner to the whole list. The following code works so if jamed_d wants, he can post it as an answer.

    table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Person> c) -> {
            table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().forEach(System.out::println);
        });
I didn't know that there was a method 'getSelectedItem**s**' but it is strange that there isn't any property for it like there is for a single item 'selectedItemProperty'.

Comment: There's no property because it is already observable (it's an `ObservableList`). It's not the reference to the list that ever changes, but the contents, so wrapping it in a property would be pretty redundant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#selectedItemProperty) the `selectedItem` property in multiple selection mode refers to the last item selected:

> The selected item property is most commonly used when the selection
>   model is set to be single selection, but is equally applicable when in
>   multiple selection mode. When in this mode, the selected item will
>   always represent the last selection made.

In your scenario, if you select "Rob", "Peter", "Max" and "John", in that order, then the selected item ends up as the last person selected ("John"), and the selected items list contains all four items. When you deselect "Peter", the last item selected is still "John". Since the `selectedItem` hasn't changed, your change listener is not invoked. When you deselect another item and then reselect it, the last selected item changes to that item, and your listener is invoked.

The "weird" border you see is simply the table's display for a cell with focus (you just clicked on it) which is not selected.

To see all the changes to the selected items, you need to register a [`ListChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.html) with the **list** of selected items:

```
table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener((Change<? extends Person> change) -> 
    System.out.println(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
```